# Compile-time array selection in C++

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, constexpr, template-specialization

I have a class which holds an array (for a filter) based on compile time parameters. For example:

```
template<class Real, unsigned N>
class foo {
public:
  // stuff ...
private:
   static const constexpr std::array<Real, unsigned N> m_h;
};
```

For instance, if `N=4` and `Real` = `double`, I would like `m_h` to be (say):

```
m_h = {0.4829629131445341,  0.8365163037378079,  0.2241438680420133, -0.129409522551260};
```

and if `N=4` and `Real` = `float`, I'd like

```
m_h = {0.4829629f, 0.8365163f, 0.2241438f, -0.1294095f};
```

If `N=6`, and `Real=double`, I'd like the numbers to be totally different:

```
m_h = {0.332670552950082615998, 0.806891509311092576494, 0.45987750211849157009, -0.1350110200102545886963899, -0.0854412738820266616928191, 0.0352262918857095366027};
```

What is the most elegant syntax to achieve this goal? The closest I have found is in Boost's [Gaussian quadrature](https://github.com/boostorg/math/blob/develop/include/boost/math/quadrature/gauss.hpp), which achieves the goal by first classifying the `Real` type by number of digits, and convertibility to float, double, and long double. Then it introduces a `foo_detail` class which gives functions `get_constants()` and selects the constants required at runtime. Boost of course supports many compilers and their varying C++11 capability, so I feel like there might be a more expressive solution using (say) C++17.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure I understand what exactly you want but... I suppose you can initialize `m_h` calling a `constexpr` template function and fully specialize it.

I mean... you can write `foo()` as follows

```
template <typename Real, std::size_t N>
class foo
 {
   private:
      static constexpr std::array<Real, N> m_h { bar<Real, N>() };
 };

template <typename Real, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::array<Real, N> foo<Real, N>::m_h;
```

and write a set of `bar()` template functions as follows

```
template <typename Real, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::array<Real, N> bar ();

template <>
constexpr std::array<double, 4u> bar<double, 4u> ()
 { return { {0.4829629131445341,  0.8365163037378079,
             0.2241438680420133, -0.129409522551260} }; }

template <>
constexpr std::array<float, 4u> bar<float, 4u> ()
 { return { {0.4829629f, 0.8365163f, 0.2241438f, -0.1294095f} }; }

template <>
constexpr std::array<double, 6u> bar<double, 6u> ()
 { return { { 0.332670552950082615998,      0.806891509311092576494,
              0.45987750211849157009,      -0.1350110200102545886963899,
             -0.0854412738820266616928191,  0.0352262918857095366027} }; }

// as many `bar()` specializations as you want
```

The following is a full compiling example (with a simplified `foo`)

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template <typename Real, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::array<Real, N> bar ();

template <>
constexpr std::array<double, 4u> bar<double, 4u> ()
 { return { {0.4829629131445341,  0.8365163037378079,
             0.2241438680420133, -0.129409522551260} }; }

template <>
constexpr std::array<float, 4u> bar<float, 4u> ()
 { return { {0.4829629f, 0.8365163f, 0.2241438f, -0.1294095f} }; }

template <>
constexpr std::array<double, 6u> bar<double, 6u> ()
 { return { { 0.332670552950082615998,      0.806891509311092576494,
              0.45987750211849157009,      -0.1350110200102545886963899,
             -0.0854412738820266616928191,  0.0352262918857095366027} }; }

template <typename Real, std::size_t N>
struct foo
 {
   static constexpr std::array<Real, N> m_h { bar<Real, N>() };
 };

template <typename Real, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::array<Real, N> foo<Real, N>::m_h;

int main ()
 {
   for ( auto f : foo<double, 4u>::m_h )
      std::cout << f << ' ';

   std::cout << std::endl;

   for ( auto f : foo<float, 4u>::m_h )
      std::cout << f << ' ';

   std::cout << std::endl;

   for ( auto f : foo<double, 6u>::m_h )
      std::cout << f << ' ';

   std::cout << std::endl;
 }
```

Or maybe, if you don't want to develop `bar()` through full specialization, you can write a single `bar()` function using a lot of `if constexpr` as follows

```
template <typename Real, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::array<Real, N> bar ()
 {
   if constexpr ( std::is_same<long double, Real>::value )
    {
      if constexpr ( 4u == N )
         return { /* something */ };
      else if constexpr ( 6u == N )
         return { /* something */ };
      // else if constexpr ( ?? == N ) ...
    }
   else if constexpr ( std::is_same<double, Real>::value )
    { 
      if constexpr ( 4u == N )
         return { {0.4829629131445341,  0.8365163037378079,
                   0.2241438680420133, -0.129409522551260} }; 
      else if constexpr ( 6u == N )
         return { { 0.332670552950082615998,      0.806891509311092576494,
                    0.45987750211849157009,      -0.1350110200102545886963899,
                   -0.0854412738820266616928191,  0.0352262918857095366027} }; 
      // else if constexpr ( ?? == N ) ...
    }
   else if constexpr ( std::is_same<float, Real>::value )
    { 
      if constexpr ( 4u == N )
         return { {0.4829629f, 0.8365163f, 0.2241438f, -0.1294095f} };
      else if constexpr ( 6u == N )
         return { /* something */ };
      // else if constexpr ( ?? == N ) ...
    }
 }
```

Comment: "Not sure I understand what exactly you want but... " it is exactly what I want. Thanks!